# malloc не выделяет нужное кол-во памяти

Tags: c++

Здраствуйте!!! По какой то причине malloc постоянно не выделяет нужное кол-во памяти. Когда я использовал маленькие значения, у меня периодически вылезала ошибка доступа к памяти. Я решил поставить большое значение. Теперь я выделяю 10000 байт, но когда инициализирую переменную EndOfStack то постоянно вылезает ошибка доступа к памяти. Я пробовал уменьшить значение (в EndOfStack вместо ((size_t)10000) я использовал ((size_t)5000)), но это не помогает.
Помогите пожалуйста.

```
    #include <malloc.h>
    using namespace std;
    class Stack {
    private:
        ~Stack() {
            ClearAll();
        }
        const size_t StackSize = 10000;
        int TypeSize = sizeof(int);
        int CountOfCells = 0;
        void* StartOfStack = 0;
        void* EndOfStack = 0;
        // Stack Pointer
        int* SP = 0;
        void CleanMemory() {
            char* vr = (char*)StartOfStack;
            for (;;) {
                if (vr == EndOfStack) {
                    break;
                }
                *vr = 0;
                vr += 0x1;
            }
        }
    public:
        Stack(bool cleanMemory) {
            StartOfStack = malloc(StackSize);
            EndOfStack = ((long long*)StartOfStack +                 ((size_t)5000));
            SP = (int*)StartOfStack;
            CountOfCells = 0;
            if (cleanMemory == true) {
                CleanMemory();
            }
}
int PushInStack(int value) {
    if (SP < EndOfStack) {          
        SP += TypeSize;
        *SP = value;
    }
    else if (SP == EndOfStack) {
        *SP = value;
    }
    return 0;
}
int PopFromStack() {
    int value = *SP;
    if (SP > StartOfStack) {
        *SP = 0;
        SP -= TypeSize;
    }
    else if (SP == StartOfStack) {
        *SP = 0;
    }
    return value;
}
int GetCountOfCells() {
    return CountOfCells;
}
int GetValueFromStack() {
    return *SP;
}
void ClearAll() {
    free(StartOfStack);
    TypeSize = 0;
    CountOfCells = 0;
    EndOfStack = 0;
    SP = 0;
    }
};
```

Comment: `((long long*)StartOfStack + ((size_t)5000))` это как `(StartOfStack + ((size_t)5000)*sizeof(long long))`. Либо выделяйте `malloc(StackSize*sizeof(long long));`, либо не приводите к `(long long*)`. Зачем кстати? У вас там ранее `int TypeSize = sizeof(int);`

Comment: В дополнение к пояснению о размерах выше... Скажите, а зачем в С++ вы вообще используете `malloc`? У вас стек `int`ов, вот и задавайте количество памяти в `int`ах — `int * StartOfStack`, `StartOfStack = new int[StackSize];`. Если вы хотите стек элементов произвольного типа — то используйте шаблоны; приведение к `void*` в любом случае кроме неудобств, ничего не дает...

Comment: А у вас код с приватным деструктором скомпилировался? У меня - нет.

Comment: да, я использую компилятор от Visual Studio. Я помещал деструктор в private потому, что меня смущает тот факт, что деструктор может вызвать кто угодно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`malloc()` выделяет всё как надо. Это вы выходите за пределы выделенной памяти.
Повторю за needKVAS и Harry - не используйте malloc, не выделяйте память в байтах - выделяйте в элементах, не делайте кучу приведений типов, в которых вы сами запутались.
А у вас всё просто - при вычислении `EndOfStack` вы выходите за границу выделенной памяти. Для примера - при выделении массива из 3 элементов какой будет последний? Последним будет `StartOfStack+2`, а не `StartOfStack+3`. А `StartOfStack+3` - это уже за пределами выделенной памяти.
Кроме того, как вам написал needKVAS, с путаницей типов вы ещё и смещение вычислили неправильно `(long long*)StartOfStack + ((size_t)5000)` это получается в байтах `StartOfStack + 5000 * 8 = 40000`. Как-бы `StartOfStack + 40000` это явно за пределами выделенной памяти.
Если вы уйдете от выделения памяти через `malloc()` и работу с указателями, то код упроститься намного. У вас останется указатель для выделения памяти, указатель на конец стека вообще не нужен и работа упрощается. И кстати - зачем деструктор приватный?

```
class Stack 
{
    private:
        const size_t Capacity = 10000; // размер выделенной памяти в элементах (не байтах) 
        int Size = 0;  // количество элементов в стеке, он же указатель на вершину стека
        int* arr = nullptr;
    public:
        Stack() { arr = new int[Capacity]{0}; } // выделение и обнуление памяти
        ~Stack() { delete[] arr; }

        int Push(int value) { 
            if(Size >= Capacity)
               throw(/*....*/) // обработать ошибку - закончилось место в стеке
            arr[Size] = value;
            Size++;
        }
        int PopFromStack() {
            if(Size == 0)
               // обработать ошибку - нет элементов в стеке
            int value = arr[Size-1];
            --Size;
            return value;
        }
};
```

Кроме того, раз вы спроектировали свой класс как владельца ресурса - динамически выделяемой памяти (сами выделяете и сами освобождаете память), вам необходимо соблюдать [правило Пяти](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D1%82%D1%80%D1%91%D1%85_(C%2B%2B)), иначе будут ошибки.

Comment: спасибо за помощь. смысл этого кода заключается в том, чтобы научится правильно работать с указателями, поэтому я использую malloc и только указатели, а не просто инициализирую массив. А насчёт деструктора, для чего он должен быть в открытом доступе? Кому надо, тот использует delete [имя переменной] и всё.

Comment: может я чего-то не понимаю, но разве смысл деструктора не в том, чтобы совершить какие-то действия при удалении переменной класса?

Comment: А оператор `delete` - внешний по отношению к классу. Как он вызовет функцию из раздела `private`? Научиться работать с указателями - это то, что я и написал. Ну можете вместо `Stack[Size]` писать `*(Stack+Size)`. Это одно и то же. Но вы углубились в приведение типов, что очень редкая операция и пользоваться ею надо только когда других вариантов нет. Не надо намеренно усложнять задачу - как вы уже испытали на себе научиться так не получится, только проблемы.

Comment: Самое основное в арифметике указателей - когда вы пишете `p+1` - это смещение не на 1 байт, а на 1 элемент указанного типа. Т.е. если `int *p`, то `p+1` - это переход к следующему элементу типа `int`, т.е. на 4 байта. Но на количество байт смотреть не надо, надо мыслить в категориях типов.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> const size_t StackSize = 10000;
> StartOfStack = malloc(StackSize);
> ```

10000 байт.

> ```
> EndOfStack = ((long long*)StartOfStack + ((size_t)5000));
> ```

5000*8 = 40000 байт.

Возможно, ты хотел

```
EndOfStack = (char *)StartOfStack + (size_t)5000;
```

> ```
> SP = (int*)StartOfStack;
> ```

А почему теперь int?

PS: Остальное не смотрел.

Comment: SP изначально был int*. Это нужно для того, чтобы нормально инициализировать память intовыми значениями.